# Unable to execute HSQL JDBC empty batch

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, hsqldb

In SQL server and oracle it is possible to run executeBatch() even if no batch is added , but it's not happening in HSQL, any alternative to resolve this problem ?

```
try 
{
    Connection con =  com.Analytix.Beans.ConnectionObjectFactory.getConnectionHSQLConnection();
    PreparedStatement pst =con.prepareStatement("insert into TEST (tname) values (?)");                                
    int[] executeUpdate = pst.executeBatch();//no batch statement Exception
    System.out.println(executeUpdate);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What's the point in executing an "empty" batch? Seems rather useless to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In my company project metadata scanning is happening of other database and detail of every column(name,datatype,size) is being inserted into local database table with one insert statement per column using addBatch() , but if some table have no column then no batch will be added , it's already implemented in SQLServer & Oracle and working fine for both environment but not supported in HSQL.

Comment: Well different DBMS behave differently. Just because the drivers for SQL Server and Oracle do it one way does not mean all drivers will do it that way. This is the price you have to pay for cross DBMS development (but really: a table with **no** columns? I don't think that is even possible in any of those DBMS)

Comment: Have you considered catching the specific SQLException and handling (e.g., ignoring) it?